# Not drawing null values using chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I'm using Chart.js to draw a chart..
My dataset have some null values,
Actually chart.js plot a line between points that are previous and successor of the null values in this way :

[image]

The red arrow indicate where are the null values

I want to find how can I not plot these null values
[image]

The configuration I use is as simple as that :

```
var lineChartData = {
            "datasets": [{
                "label": "defi score",
                "data": data,
                "pointStrokeColor": "#fff",
                "fillColor": "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                "pointColor": "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                "strokeColor": "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            }],
            "labels": labels
        };


        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart_per_week").getContext("2d");
        var myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
            responsive: true,
            scaleFontColor: "#FF5972",
            bezierCurve: false
        });
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Breaking (Broken) Lines using Chart.js

You can extend the line chart type to do this

---

**Preview**

### [image]

**Script**

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
  name: "LineAlt",
  initialize: function (data) {
    var fillColors = [];
    var strokeColors = [];
    data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
      if (dataset.data.indexOf(null) !== -1) {
        fillColors.push(dataset.fillColor);
        strokeColors.push(dataset.strokeColor);
        dataset.fillColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
        dataset.strokeColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0)"
      }
    })

    Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

    var self = this;
    data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
      if (dataset.data.indexOf(null) !== -1) {
        self.datasets[i]._saved = {
          fillColor: fillColors.shift(),
          strokeColor: strokeColors.shift()
        }
      }
    })
  },
  draw: function () {
    Chart.types.Line.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);

    // from Chart.js library code
    var hasValue = function (point) {
      return point.value !== null;
    },
    nextPoint = function (point, collection, index) {
      return Chart.helpers.findNextWhere(collection, hasValue, index) || point;
    },
    previousPoint = function (point, collection, index) {
      return Chart.helpers.findPreviousWhere(collection, hasValue, index) || point;
    };

    var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
    var self = this;
    ctx.save();
    this.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
      if (dataset._saved) {
        ctx.lineWidth = self.options.datasetStrokeWidth;
        ctx.strokeStyle = dataset._saved.strokeColor;
        ctx.fillStyle = dataset._saved.fillColor;

        // adapted from Chart.js library code
        var pointsWithValues = Chart.helpers.where(dataset.points, hasValue);
        dataset.points.forEach(function (point, index) {
          if (index === 0 || (hasValue(point) && !hasValue(dataset.points[index - 1])))
            point.start = true;
        });
        var currentStartPoint = undefined;
        Chart.helpers.each(pointsWithValues, function (point, index) {
          if (point.start) {
            if (currentStartPoint) {
              ctx.lineTo(pointsWithValues[index - 1].x, self.scale.endPoint);
              ctx.lineTo(currentStartPoint.x, self.scale.endPoint);
              ctx.closePath();
              ctx.fill();
            }

            currentStartPoint = point;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(point.x, point.y);
          }
          else {
            if (self.options.bezierCurve) {
              var previous = previousPoint(point, pointsWithValues, index);
              ctx.bezierCurveTo(
                previous.controlPoints.outer.x,
                previous.controlPoints.outer.y,
                point.controlPoints.inner.x,
                point.controlPoints.inner.y,
                point.x,
                point.y
              );
            }
            else {
              ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);
            }
          }

          ctx.stroke();
        }, this);

        ctx.lineTo(pointsWithValues[pointsWithValues.length - 1].x, self.scale.endPoint);
        ctx.lineTo(currentStartPoint.x, self.scale.endPoint);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
      }
    })

    ctx.restore();
  }
});
```

and then

```
var data = {
    ...
    datasets: [
        {
            ...
            data: [65, 59, null, 81, 52, 62, null, 56, 40],
        }
    ],
};

...
new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data);
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/hbrhz2q4/

Comment: Thank you very much, that's works very fine for me, I took it as the correct answer ....

Comment: This was the correct answer when it was written, but there is a better way now as in Selay's answer below

Answer (score 37):

In case you still reach this page, New version supports skipping missing data. . 
If you want the lines to be connected by skipping missing data, you can set spanGaps: true in the options.

Then if you have null or NaN for missing data, it will skip it and connect to the next point.

```
.....
 showTooltips: true,
        options: {
             spanGaps: true,
  ......
```

[Documentation here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-chart-options)

Comment: Thanks Selay, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: `null`value doesn't seem to work. doc states to set empty points to `NaN`

Comment: @CédricFrançoys can you please share the link

Comment: @RahulHindocha https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.8.0/charts/line.html#line-styling

Comment: best answer. most simple and the document clearly says to use spanGaps if you have null values

Comment: FWIW in 2.9 with log scales this is broken (`null` data points both appear and show up as at the bottom of the graph view pane). I guess I need to figure out how chart.js was reshuffled for v3 adn hope it's fixed there...

Comment: ...it is fixed there

Answer (score 14):

I know this is pretty old, but I think there is a better solution now. Replace all your null values with Number.NaN

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#line-chart-chart-options

Below is a data point I replaced with NaN on the red line

[image: Broken Line]

Comment: Best answer so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if ChartJS itself can natively do this.

However one way I did something similar was to make the line graph out of multiple datasets. One dataset would end when a null value is reached, and the next dataset would start. This would of course requires parsing all this data before passing it into var linechartdata

You can make all the datasets have the same colors and highlights and the graph should render with spaces where null data would have been found.

Comment: Hi, Do you suggest another librairie to draw charts ? thank you

Comment: Actually, to parse data, I asked a question for that :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516775/build-arrays-using-an-array-javascript

so I got my datasets with the null values ;) ...