# Build arrays using an array (javascript)

Tags: javascript

How may I build a function in javascript that do the following :

Input :

```
var data = [null, 1, 2, 3, null, null, 2, null, 4]
```

output:

```
dataset = [ 
[null, 1, 2, 3, null, null, null, null, null],
[null, null, null, null, null, null, 2, null, null],
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 4], 
]
```

in fact in this example, my input have 3 set of no null values : these sets are : [1, 2, 3], [2] and [4]

from these sets I want builds arrays that have these values (of not null sets) and that conserve the same index as the input array

---

Thank you

Comment: Can you explain how the input becomes the output?

Comment: It is based on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513679/split-array-using-null-separator

Comment: How would you know, @CodeiSir? I believe it would be frowned upon to have multiple accounts as one could be tempted to up-vote one's own question(s).

Comment: the input to output doesn't make any sense.  Why does the first one arbitrarily retain three non-null values when the other two arrays only retain one each?

Comment: Ok, I ll edit my question, just a sec, sorry

Comment: I was planning to accept the challenge and started working on it. But when I started, I had too many questions. I believe and *assume* that the length of each of the row is the length of the array. `var rowSize = data.length;`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I assumed the same, but it doesn't make sense where the array splits off to a new row.  I could understand one non-null value per row, or even splitting it into thirds, but neither of those work.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Rightly said. Same thing.

Comment: in fact in this example, my input have 3 set of no null values : these sets are : [1, 2, 3], [2] and [4]

from these sets I want builds arrays that have these values (of not null sets) and that conserve the same index as the input array

Comment: @taboubim Yes, got it.

Comment: @AndrueAnderson lol, no I am just an Oracle^^ ... that worked on the question I linked made by the same autor of this post, wich has the same structure like this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a proposal with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var data = [null, 1, 2, 3, null, null, 2, null, 4],
    result = [];

data.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
    if (a !== null) {
        if (r === null) {
            result.push(Array.apply(null, { length: data.length }).map(function () { return null; }));
        }
        result[result.length - 1][i] = a;
    }
    return a;
}, null);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my result:

```
var data = [null, 1, 2, 3, null, null, 2, null, 4];
var dataset = [[]];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if(!data[i]) {
    if(!data[i-1]) {
      dataset[dataset.length-1].push(data[i]);
    } else {
      for(var fillRight = i; fillRight < data.length; fillRight++) {
        dataset[dataset.length-1].push(null);
      }
      dataset.push([null]);
      for(var fillLeft = 0; fillLeft < i; fillLeft++) {
        dataset[dataset.length-1].push(null);
      }
    }
  } else {
    dataset[dataset.length-1].push(data[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are..

```js
var a = [null, 1, 2, 3, null, 2, null, null, 4, null];
var b = []; // result
for (var arr = null, i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i] === null) {
    arr = null;
  } else {
    if (!arr) {
      if(b.length) b[b.length-1] = b[b.length-1].concat(Array(a.length-i).map(function(){return null}))
      b.push(arr = Array.apply(null, Array(i)).map(function() {
        return null
      }));
    }
    arr.push(a[i]);
  }
}
document.body.textContent = JSON.stringify(b); // just print the result
```

based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34513955/4339170

I only added the lines:

```
      if(b.length) b[b.length-1] = b[b.length-1].concat(Array(a.length-i).map(function(){return null}))
      b.push(arr = Array.apply(null, Array(i)).map(function() {return null}));
```

where the first fills up the end with nulls when a section is done, and the second fills up the front of a new section with nulls

Comment: Hi CodeiSir, Good thank you, however it does not do the all the job :

The result I got is this : 
[null, 1, 2, 3, undefined × 5]
[null, null, null, null, null, 2, undefined × 2]
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 4]

I guess the result table should be filled by null before enter the loop ?

Comment: Well you could also fill up an array with nulls first and then just place the new items at the correct position. Would be more performant, by I don't have the time right now

Comment: @taboubim it gives me `[[null,1,2,3,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,2,null,null],[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,4]]` as you can see in the output